# HTTPS communication between client and server in android

Tags: android, ssl, https, client-server, ssl-certificate

I am new to android.

I have used below code to interact with my Server. My website got Https security.

```
    protected Void doInBackground(Void...params)
    {
        HttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost;
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> param= new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        httpPost = new HttpPost("https://xxxx.co.in/xxx.php");

        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobileSerialNumber",mobileSerialNumber));
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("NFCSupportedMobile",NFCSupportedMobile));
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ConnectedTo_REVUE_Wifi",ConnectedTo_REVUE_Wifi));
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ConnectedToWifi",ConnectedToWifi));
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ConnectedToMobileInternet",ConnectedToMobileInternet));

        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            }

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            //read content
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Server Connection", "Server connection failed");
            e.printStackTrace();
            iconnectionProblem = true;
        }
```

When I request my server with above code I got below error.

```html
03-16 23:11:59.467  20262-20480/com.revu.revu W/System.err﹕ javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: <revue.co.in> != <*.prod.sin2.secureserver.net> OR <*.prod.sin2.secureserver.net> OR <prod.sin2.secureserver.net>
03-16 23:11:59.487  20262-20480/com.revu.revu W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:190)
03-16 23:11:59.487  20262-20480/com.revu.revu W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier.verify(BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier.java:59)
03-16 23:11:59.487  20262-20480/com.revu.revu W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:119)
03-16 23:11:59.487  20262-20480/com.revu.revu W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:100)
03-16 23:11:59.488  20262-20480/com.revu.revu W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:393)
03-16 23:11:59.488  20262-20480/com.revu.revu W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:170)
03-16 23:11:59.488  20262-20480/com.revu.revu W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:169)
03-16 23:11:59.488  20262-20480/com.revu.revu W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:124)
03-16 23:11:59.488  20262-20480/com.revu.revu W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:379)
03-16 23:11:59.488  20262-20480/com.revu.revu W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:580)
03-16 23:11:59.488  20262-20480/com.revu.revu W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:503)
03-16 23:11:59.488  20262-20480/com.revu.revu W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:481)
```

The above error says that SSL problem. How can I allow **https** communication between client and server in android.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using the deprecated Http Client and not `HttpsURLConnection`? If so you may need some additional setup now that the code is deprecated. See this for more info: http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client

Comment: I have developed android app on Android Version Kitkat. Now I have added SSL security using HTTPS for my website. At that time I used HttpsClient to communicate with Server. I can change my code, but I need to use secure communication between client and server when I make requests.